# How to move a rectangle in python using pygame in this code?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to move a rectangle with the arrow keys, so far I only can draw the rectangle but I don't get the keyhandler to work.
I'm a newbie in python and pygame.

This is my main.py:

```
import pygame
import time
import random
from Player import *

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()
game_over = False

# Color
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GRAY = (192, 192, 192)

# Setting up the window
surfaceWidth = 800
surfaceHeight = 500

surface = pygame.display.set_mode((surfaceWidth, surfaceHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption("Rectangle Runner")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Player(surface, surface_height, surface_width, size, jump_height, color)
player = Player(surface, surfaceHeight, surfaceWidth, 50, 200, BLACK)

# Game Loop
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_over = True
        if game_over == True:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    surface.fill(GRAY)
    #Player.draw()
    player.keyHandling()
    player.checkBoundaries()
    player.draw()
    #Obstacle.draw()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
# This code shall be unreachable
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

This is the Player.py:

```
import pygame


class Player:

    def __init__(self, surface, surface_height, surface_width, size, jump_height, color):
        self.surface = surface
        self.surface_height = surface_height
        self.surface_width = surface_width
        self.size = size
        self.jump_height = jump_height
        self.color = color

        self.x = (0 + (self.surface_width/10))
        self.y = self.surface_height - self.size

        self.x_move = 0
        self.y_move = 0

        self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.color, [self.x, self.y, self.size, self.size])


    def keyHandling(self):
        # Draw the player
        #pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.color,
                        #[self.x, self.y, self.size, self.size])
        # KeyListener
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    self.y_move = -10
                    #self.y += self.y_move
                    #self.rect.move_ip(0, -10)
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.x_move = -5
                    #self.x += self.x_move
                    #self.rect.move_ip(-5, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.x_move = 5
                    #self.x += self.x_move
                    #self.rect.move_ip(5, 0)
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    self.y_move = 0
                    #self.y += self.y_move
                    #self.rect.move_ip(0, 10)
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.x_move = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.x_move = 0
        self.x += self.x_move
        self.y += self.y_move


    def checkBoundaries(self):
        # Checking for Boundaries
        #if self.y <= self.jump_height:
        #    self.y_move = -10
        if self.y > self.surface_height - self.size:
            self.y_move = 0
        if self.y <= self.jump_height + self.size:
            self.y_move = -10

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.color, [self.x, self.y, self.size, self.size])




        #pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.color,[self.x, self.y, self.size, self.size])
```

I need help. I'm thinking thru this the whole day.
Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that `pygame.event.get()` is a generator. Each item that is obtained from it can ONLY be obtained once. Hence, each time the clock ticks, you are grabbing everything within the events generator and they are all destroyed. Next, when the Player object iterates over `pygame.event.get`, it does nothing, as the generator was already made empty. See [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) about generators.

What you need to do is catch the KEYDOWN event in the `main.py` module and then pass key information onto the Player object.

Replace the main loop in `main.py` with the following:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_over = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            player.keyDown(event.key)
        if game_over == True:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    surface.fill(GRAY)
    player.checkBoundaries()
    player.draw()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Remove the `keyHandling` method from `Player.py` and replace with the following method:

```
def keyDown(self, key):
    if key == pygame.K_w:
        self.y -= 10
    elif key == pygame.K_a:
        self.x -= 10
    elif key == pygame.K_d:
        self.x += 10
```

This now removes the issue with the generator.

[Full code](https://pastebin.com/jkqqcCm7)

Comment: Also note that the program moves in a very clunky manner. Perhaps a forces/vectors system would fix this (I have implemented one in the past for pygame specifically) and make it a lot smoother if that happens to be something you want to add.

Comment: This fixed my problem! If you have a code example of a forces/vectors system I would really appreciate it!!

Comment: Actually, `pygame.event.get()` is not returning a generator; it's returning an ordinary list. If you save the list in a variable `events = pygame.event.get()` it's possible to iterate over the list multiple times. Could be useful to know if you want to pass the event list around to multiple objects (for example, `keyHandling ` could take whole event list instead of single events), or want to iterate over all events and save them for the next frame. It's the function `pygame.event.get()` that will return all the events that have happened since the last call.